# Electricity transfer basics

Tags: voltage, generator, power-generation

First off, I'm sorry if this is something that's been covered before. I tried scrubbing the internet but can't quite find an answer to my questions. I have o my a very remedial amount of electric knowledge but am trying to self-educate. As such I am trying to get a grasp for the basic concept of transferring power from source A into item B.

So let's say I have a very basic home grid set up. I have a small wind generator that's feeding into a generator of some kind. My first question is, when the generator is providing power to my house, say at X amount of power, but my house is only using X-5 power, what happens to the extra electricity that doesn't get used? Does it just stay in the system or dissipate?

My second question pertains to the next step of this process. Do you need to line up the voltage from the input into your home grid with the outlets? For instance I recently learned the typical American outlets are 120 volts, but say my generator is outputting 240 volts. How does this difference get corrected?

And my final question is how exactly power is drawn into things. So my wall outlet can output 120 volts, but I plug in something like a 12v tool. Since electricity is being pushed into the system how does my 12v tool only take on 12v instead of being force-fed the full 120v?

Again I have very little knowledge about even these probably basic concepts but I would like to learn. I appreciate any time spent on this.

Comment: First I was interested to answering your first two questions but after reading the third, I realize you are super novice to electricity. Please go learn something more fundamental using batteries and LEDs before going into high voltage energy generation systems. I worry you might kill yourself.

Comment: I was also worried by the second question

Comment: If you plug in a 12v tool to your wall socket, it **will** be force-fed 120v. At best, the magic smoke will be released from the tool. At worst, you will be smoked as well.

Comment: To make the point of @Neil_UK clearer: **that 12V tool might catch fire or even explode in your hands!**

Answer (score 3):

> So let's say I have a very basic home grid set up.

Before we start, because of the nature of your questions, I want to advise you not to actually connect anything you designed to the mains until you have a much stronger understanding of electrical design. You could easily start a fire or electrocute yourself or someone else if you mess around with your current level of understanding.

> when the generator is providing power to my house, say at X amount of power, but my house is only using X-5 power, what happens to the extra electricity that doesn't get used? Does it just stay in the system or dissipate?

There is nowhere for the energy to be stored in a typical residential electrical system, something else has to adjust. I don't work in power and I don't know practically what's most likely to happen but I would guess that either

- The generator output voltage increases so that loads in the system (light bulbs, for example) use more power
- The mechanical resistance of the generator decreases so that it draws less power from the windmill

or

- Internal losses in the generator increase so that the excess power gets converted to heat

> Do you need to line up the voltage from the input into your home grid with the outlets?

Yes, if you connect a generator to the rest of the grid it must be carefully controlled to match the grid in not just voltage, but also frequency, and phase.

> For instance I recently learned the typical American outlets are 120 volts, but say my generator is outputting 240 volts. How does this difference get corrected?

Probably your generator gets burned out or you blow a fuse.

> So my wall outlet can output 120 volts, but I plug in something like a 12v tool. Since electricity is being pushed into the system how does my 12v tool only take on 12v instead of being force-fed the full 120v?

Normally you use a transformer (often called a "wall wart") to convert the mains voltage to a lower one like 12 or 9 V.

Then you use a rectifier (which is often also included in the wall wart) to convert from AC to DC voltage.

Then, for many loads, you use a regulator (again, also likely to be included in a wall wart) to maintain the voltage at a desired value, like 12 V +/- 0.2 V, rather than let it drift as the current drawn by the load varies.

Answer (score 0):

> So let's say I have a very basic home grid set up. I have a small wind generator that's feeding into a generator of some kind. My first question is, when the generator is providing power to my house, say at X amount of power, but my house is only using X-5 power, what happens to the extra electricity that doesn't get used? Does it just stay in the system or dissipate?

If your house is on-grid, you should only be using a properly designed grid-tied inverter to connect your wind turbine.

In this scenario, the excess power is just pushed out through your incoming supply cable, and powers your neighbors' houses.

Anything else would be dangerous, and would quite likely blow a fuse/trip a breaker/go bang the moment you connected it (because it wouldn't be in phase with the supply).

> My second question pertains to the next step of this process. Do you need to line up the voltage from the input into your home grid with the outlets? For instance I recently learned the typical American outlets are 120 volts, but say my generator is outputting 240 volts. How does this difference get corrected?

A proper grid-tied inverter would simply refuse to work, probably showing an error message on its display to say the supply is outside its specification.

Any other kind of generator will probably blow a fuse/trip a breaker/go bang.

> And my final question is how exactly power is drawn into things. So my wall outlet can output 120 volts, but I plug in something like a 12v tool. Since electricity is being pushed into the system how does my 12v tool only take on 12v instead of being force-fed the full 120v?

The 12V tool will be supplied with 120V, which is 10 times its rating.  It will go bang (spot a theme here?).